# Rails isn't running destroy callbacks for has_many through join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two AR models and a third `has_many :through` join model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :movies, through: :ratings
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :users, through: :ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie

  after_destroy do
    puts 'destroyed'
  end    
end
```

Occasionally, a user will want to drop a movie directly (without directly destroying the rating). However, when I do:

```
# puts user.movie_ids
# => [1,2,3]

user.movie_ids = [1, 2]
```

the rating's `after_destroy` callback isn't called, although the join record is deleted appropriately. If I modify my user model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :movies, 
    through: :ratings,
    before_remove: proc { |u, m| Rating.where(movie: m, user: u).destroy_all }
end
```

Everything works fine, but this is really ugly, and Rails then tries to delete the join model a second time.

How can I use a `dependent: :destroy` strategy for this association, rather than `dependent: :delete`?

Comment: from doco *If using with the [`:through`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) option, the association on the join model must be a `belongs_to`, and **the records which get deleted are the join records, rather than the associated records**.*

Answer (score 26):

Answering my own question, since this was difficult to Google, and the answer is super counter-intuitive (although I don't know what the ideal interface would be).

First, the situation is described thoroughly here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7618. However, the specific answer is buried about halfway down the page, and the issue was closed (even though it is still an issue in current Rails versions).

You can specify `dependent: :destroy` for these types of join model destructions, by adding the option to the `has_many :through` command, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :movies, 
    through: :ratings,
    dependent: :destroy
end
```

This is counter-intuitive because in normal cases, `dependent: :destroy` will destroy that specific association's object(s).

For example, if we had `has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy` here, all of a user's ratings would be destroyed when that user was destroyed.

We certainly don't want to destroy the specific movie objects here, because they may be in use by other users/ratings. However, Rails magically knows that we want to destroy the join record, not the association record, in this case.

Comment: voted up for clearly explaining the intent... Who knows this was the intention. But I am with your thought!

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved my day,