# After destroy not being called on association destruction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models setup.

```
class Space
  has_many :locations, through: :location_spaces
  has_many :location_spaces, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :space
end

class Location
  has_many :spaces, through: :location_spaces
  has_many :location_spaces, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :location
end

class LocationSpace
  belongs_to :location,     inverse_of: :location_spaces
  belongs_to :space,        inverse_of: :location_spaces
end
```

If I create a SpaceLocation by modifying the location_ids on the Space model , this also triggers the AFTER_CREATE callback for SpaceLocation.

However when you update the space model, and set the location_ids to [], this deletes the SpaceLocation. However doesn't call the after_destroy callback. Looking at the sql, the destruction is made.

Why isn't the after_destroy callback called? 
I have tried every "after" callback, including after_touched, and nothing was called.

Comment: This answers my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629680/rails-isnt-running-destroy-callbacks-for-has-many-through-join-model

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs for `has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Delete+or+destroy-3F):

> There is also a `clear` method which is the same as `delete_all`, except that it returns the association rather than the records which have been deleted.

From the [docs for `delete_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all):

> Deletes the records matching `conditions` without instantiating the records first, and hence not calling the `destroy` method nor invoking callbacks.